# Formatting issues on x-axis and y-axis in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a latex code to generate graphs from a text file. The contents of the text file are like this:

```
0.01    0.119693    48.43196
0.02    0.1310796   6214.208
0.03    0.1289268   12973.42
0.04    0.1286408   17064.04
0.05    0.128663    19556.76
0.06    0.1289252   21224.36
0.07    0.1283098   22407.22
```

Here is the latex code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=6cm,compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    scale only axis,
    xlabel={$Applied\; Load\;(packets\;per\;cycle\;per\;node) $},
    xtick={0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.05,0.06,0.07},
    ylabel={$Throughput\;(in\;flits\;per\;cycles)$},
    ytick={0,0.05,0.1,0.15},
    legend style={font=\small,at={(0.5,0.96)},anchor=north,style={nodes={right}}},
    legend pos=outer north east,
    legend cell align=left,
]
\addplot[color=red,mark=*, mark options={fill=red}]
    table[x index=0,y index=1] {DOR_data.txt};

    \legend{DOR}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    scale only axis,
    xlabel={$Applied\; Load\;(packets\;per\;cycle\;per\;node) $},
    xtick={0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.05,0.06,0.07},
    ylabel={$Delay\;(in\;cycles)$},
    ytick={0,1000,5000,10000,15000,20000},
    legend style={font=\small,at={(0.5,0.96)},anchor=north,style={nodes={right}}},
    legend pos=outer north east,
    legend cell align=left,
]
\addplot[color=red,mark=*, mark options={fill=red}]
    table[x index=0,y index=2] {DOR_data.txt};


    \legend{DOR}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This is how the graph comes out:

[image]

Now, there are 2 issues:

1. There is no y-axis pointers on the graph on the left.
2. In x-axis, 10^(-2) is overlapping with the x-label. I want them to show as 0.01, 0.02 etc.

This same code has worked for me previously. This is weird.

Comment: Unrelated comment: your axis labels are just text, so don't write them in math mode. E.g., use `xlabel={Applied Load (packets per cycle per node)}`. If you want it in italics, use `\textit{Applied ...}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need add (for example) `ytick={0.12,0.125,0.13}` since the range of your data is different. Then you can customize the labels too. adding `scaled ticks=false,` removes the $10^{-2}$ and then using `xticklabels` you can name them 0.01, 0.02 and so on. Here is an example of figure 1

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
  scale only axis,
  xlabel={\textit{Applied Load (packets per cycle per node)}},
  xtick={0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.05,0.06,0.07},
  xticklabels={0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.05,0.06,0.07},
  ylabel={\textit{Throughput (in flits per cycles)}},
  scaled ticks=false,
  ytick={0.12,0.125,0.13},
  yticklabels={0.12,0.125,0.13},
  legend style={font=\small,at={(0.5,0.96)},anchor=north,style={nodes= {right}}}, 
  legend pos=outer north east,
  legend cell align=left,
  ]
  \addplot[color=red,mark=*, mark options={fill=red}]
  table[x index=0,y index=1] {data1.dat};
 \legend{DOR}

 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Rather than specifying the xticklabels, I'd change the formatting of the numbers. `scaled x ticks=false,
xticklabel style={
/pgf/number format/fixed,
/pgf/number format/precision=3}`